# Cut data from a cell based on data in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

[This is how it is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B7wL.jpg)

[This Is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpM34.jpg)

In the image it can be seen that ColumnB has "Week-off" and "0". 
I require a macro which would Cut data from ColumnA if the corresponding ColumnB has "Week-Off"  and paste it in the next empty row in ColumnA.

I have this but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 2) = "Week-off" Then
            Range("a").Cut Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 1).Cut...`

Comment: Perhaps you should not be **cutting** the cell (which affects the layout of the sheet) but copy the value, clear the cell, and deploy the value in the new position.

Comment: @tim williams That helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was posted as comment by @Tim Williams hence posting it as answer.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Long

For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 2) = "Week-off" Then
        Cell(i,1).Cut Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End If
Next

End Sub
```